# Mulitmonitor Setup on Optimus Laptop stopped working after playing with Compiz Settings [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: compiz, nvidia-optimus, multiple-monitors

I recently got a second display (HDMI) and connected it to the unused HDMI out on the laptop side by side with the old VGA display to use both simultanously as an extended display. Initially, it didnt work and both screen would blank whenever I connected the other one, but as soon as only one was connected, that one would work. After a reboot with both connected however, it automagically started working for 2 weeks.

Until last night - I had been playing around with compiz settings to get the most out of the new screen real estate - it went back to the initial behaviour.
I did restore the compiz settings via a previous settings-file to exactly how they had been, to no avail. I dont think my changes there even caused it, but then again, I didnt do anything else.

Thanks to my Windows Dualboot Installation, I could check it's not hardware related; in Windows, extended Desktop works all right.
I then turned of automatic login and saw the lightdm login screen comes up normally on both screens, but once I input my password, they both go black.
POST Screen and Grub/Burg as well as plymouth-bootscreen also come up normally on both.

NOTE: I dont use the built in laptop screen at all - I always had it deactivated through Ubuntus standard display gui and it also doesnt light up when the error occurs.

System: Laptop Acer Aspire Timeline 3830TG with Ubuntu 16.04

Graphics: onboard Intel and additionally dedicated NVIDIA GT540M GPU (the latter not in use, I doublechecked with `nvidia-settings` AND `prime-select query` !), with 'Optimus'-technology for using/switching both. No customizations there, I left everything vanilla, using nouveau- instead of proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Maybe a regular Ubuntu update disimproved something, I have no clue..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!
After some hotplugging/unplugging and logging off/on, the laptop screen suddenly was on, and there I could open the display gui and see both external displays were recognized but deactivated, activated them, and voila.

Some how Ubuntu had kept my 'dont use laptop screen' setting whenever at least one external display was connected, but deactivated both external screens when both were connected, because something got reset when I messed with Compiz and Ubuntu was now every time confused with the 2 external displays and turned them off precautiously for some reason until I would choose to use them - except I couldnt, because the laptop screen off setting persisted/came back once I connected them. Looks like a bug to me.

The straight forward way would have been this, I believe:
disconnect one, then turn on laptop display, then connect the second one as well,then have laptop screen to acticvate both ext. displays and deactivate built-in screen with the gui, and be happy.